# Не работает setImageURI

Tags: android

В манифесте фильтр прописан:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

В onCreate:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if( Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals( getIntent().getAction().toString() ) ){
        ImageView image = ( ImageView )findViewById( R.id.imageView );
        image.setImageURI( ( Uri )getIntent().getExtras().get( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM ) );
    }
}
```

Но это не работает. Запускаю на Android 4.0. Просто открываю, или открываю через выборку возможных приложений при отправке изображения - нет разницы. Поменял строку

```
image.setImageURI( ( Uri )getIntent().getExtras().get( Intent.EXTRA_STREAM ) );
```

На

```
image.setImageResource( R.drawable.ic_launcher );
```

И соответственно работает. Т.е. вопрос в том, что я не правильно из внешнего потока изображение вытаскиваю? Если да, то как его вытащить правильно?

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: права на интернет дал? картинка приходит? дебажить надо

Comment: Интернет не используется. Картинка уже на девайсе. Открываю картинку, захожу в меню, отправить в приложение, выбираю свое приложение. Точно так же как можно отправить в VK, BlogSpot etc + MyApplication

Comment: А чо хотели то? Не совсем ясно чего добиваетесь?

Comment: Кликаешь на фотографию, кликаешь отправить в такое-то приложение, выбираешь свое приложение и это изображение там отображается.

Comment: Тогда почему `ACTION_SEND`? Надо `ACTION_VIEW`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уточнили б Вы откуда отправить пытаетесь...
Если Вам нужно открыть картинку в своём приложении из любого файлового менеджера - то всё банально:

```
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
</intent-filter>

image.setImageURI(getIntent().getData());
```

Comment: Угу именно так и надо